# Is there a way (maybe shortcut) to select any element using keyboard after entering chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Lets say i use the shortcut "Ctrl + Shift + I" to enter chrome inspector, is there a way to immediately after that select the first (or any) element in the inspector with keyboard.

Comment: Press the icon on the top left (or Ctrl+Shift+C). It allows you to click an element in the browser to select it. Or just click on an HTML tag.

Comment: Sorry, i meant without having to click on anything (using the keyboard).

Comment: One way is to use the arrow keys (up/down to move up/down, right to expand a tag). Or you could press the Escape key to go to the console and select an element from there. Probably not what you're looking for, though.